# convert from 16 bit to 32 bit in assembly irvine 32

Tags: assembly, irvine32

I running a code in assembly language, however I have a register called dx that I want print it, I do not think that I can print this value without going from 16 to 32 bit register is their is a way to do it?
this is how I wrote it but I do not think it is correct:

```
        mov dx,eax
        mov edx, offset message3
        call writestring
        call writedec
```

Comment: Try `movzx eax, dx`. That moves the value from `DX` to `EAX` amd zero extends it (as an unsigned value).

Comment: Destination is on the left, so even if `mov dx,eax` did work, it would be overwriting your DX with whatever was in AX.  Right before you overwrite the full EDX with a pointer.

Comment: [NASM - How do you move an 8-bit register into a full 32-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32836589) is about an 8-bit source, but the same instruction works for a 16-bit source.